# How to select the right parent view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have a **child view controller** called by two view controllers placed in different places in the **storyboard**. In this child there is a button to close the actual view, i want to assign an **IBAction** or a **Segue** to connect this view with is real **parent view controller**.

Maybe i'm wrong but it's possible to do this with an **Unwind Segue**?? This is the first time i have to use those, somebody could help me please?

Thanks a lot! Peace

Comment: What's the relationship between the parent and the child? Is it pushed on the navigation controller or presented (modally)? Then you can use either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the relationship between the parent and the child? Is it pushed on the navigation controller or presented (modally)? Then you can use in the case of `UINavigationController`

```
- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated; // Returns the popped controller.
```

or in case of presented (modally) viewcontroller

```
- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated: (BOOL)flag completion: (void (^)(void))completion NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
```

You can also use unwinding segues of course, [check out this tutorial](http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2013/2/5/unwind-segues).

Answer (score 0):

No matter the viewController you're using, you can access its parent by calling :

```
// < iOS 5
[myViewController parentViewController]

// >= iOS 5
[myViewController presentingViewController]
```

After getting it you'll just have to check which one it :

```
if ([[myViewController presentingViewController] isKindOfClass:[myParentClassA class]])
{
  // do anything
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create unwind methods with the same name in both parent view controllers:

```
- (IBAction)unwindToThisViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {

}
```

The unwind mechanism automatically will walk through the responder chain and find the correct parent view controller